# default wordpress gallery pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination, gallery, default

I am looking everywhere for a plugin to divide my default WordPress 3.8.3 gallery containing 80 photos into 4 pages of 20 photos through pagination. I have looked online for 2 days now and haven't been able to find anything... Anyone knows of a plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if you manged to resolve this. I do have a solution for this.

Here is what i have done:
First created the gallery on the specific page in the wordpress backend. Then in my functions.php file i added the following code:

```
add_filter('post_gallery', 'filter_gallery', 10, 2);
function filter_gallery($output, $attr) 
{
    global $post;



    //GALLERY SETUP STARTS HERE----------------------------------------//
    if (isset($attr['orderby'])) {
        $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby($attr['orderby']);
        if (!$attr['orderby'])
            unset($attr['orderby']);
    }
    //print_r($attr);
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order ID',
        'id' => $post->ID,
        'itemtag' => 'dl',
        'icontag' => 'dt',
        'captiontag' => 'dd',
        'columns' => 3,
        'size' => 'thumbnail',
        'include' => '',
        'exclude' => ''
    ), $attr));

    $id = intval($id);
    if ('RAND' == $order) $orderby = 'none';

    if (!empty($include)) {
        $include = preg_replace('/[^0-9,]+/', '', $include);
        $_attachments = get_posts(array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby));

        $attachments = array();
        foreach ($_attachments as $key => $val) {
            $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
        }
    }
    if (empty($attachments)) return '';
    //GALLERY SETUP END HERE------------------------------------------//





    //PAGINATION SETUP START HERE-------------------------------------//
    $current = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $per_page = 24;
    //$offset = ($page-1) * $per_page;
    $offset = ($current-1) * $per_page;
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer


    $total = sizeof($attachments);
    $total_pages = round($total/$per_page);
    if($total_pages < ($total/$per_page))
    {   $total_pages = $total_pages+1;
    }
    //PAGINATION SETUP END HERE-------------------------------------//














    //GALLERY OUTPUT START HERE---------------------------------------//
    $output = "<div class=\"gallery-images\">\n";
    $counter = 0;
    $pos = 0;
    foreach ($attachments as $id => $attachment) 
    {   $pos++;
        //$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'medium');
        //$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'thumbnail');
        //$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'full');  

        if(($counter < $per_page)&&($pos > $offset))
        {   $counter++;
            $largetitle = get_the_title($attachment->ID);
            $largeimg = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'large');  
            $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, array(100,100));        
            $output .= " <a href=\"{$largeimg[0]}\" data-lightbox=\"example-set\" title=\"{$largetitle}\"><img src=\"{$img[0]}\" width=\"{$img[1]}\" height=\"{$img[2]}\" alt=\"\" /></a>\n";
        }

    }  
    $output .= "<div class=\"clear\"></div>\n";
    $output .= "</div>\n";
    //GALLERY OUTPUT ENDS HERE---------------------------------------//






    //PAGINATION OUTPUT START HERE-------------------------------------//
    $output .= paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace($big,'%#%',esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => $current,
        'total' => $total_pages,
        'prev_text'    => __('&laquo;'),
        'next_text'    => __('&raquo;')
    ) );
    //PAGINATION OUTPUT ENDS HERE-------------------------------------//





    return $output;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a million Marc, Do you know how could I change the thumbnail size and limit the size to 3 thumbnails colum width,and also include a bit of text from photo description below the photo? I appreciate you help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Marcus. Sorry for the delay in my response. Ok. So if you want to change the size of the image. Ammend this line: $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, array(100,100)); and if you want to add text to a photo. I would suggest you do it on the lightbox popup. Then all you need ot do is add a title tag with your text in there in the <a href>.

Comment: Hi @Marc. I'm trying to implement this code snippet but instead of working properly it just adds a big block of code to the top of the page. Can you shed any light on the situation?

Comment: Hello @Marc I'm tring to using this code for post content. if the post status is draft it works. if not it doesn't work. you can see my content from here. http://goo.gl/vpf5rR And the codes: http://goo.gl/5iDgiA What the reason can be? Thanks..